# Reusing 'data' passed in the jquery-ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery's `.ajax()` method on a button click.

I wanted to know if there a way in whcih I can use the data that I passed in the data-part of the AJAX call in my success() function.

This is my code,

```
$.ajax({
  url: //my URL here..
  type: 'POST',
  data:{
    projDets : projDetailsArray,
  },
  datatype:'html',
  error: function(){
    alert('Error loading Project Information');     
  },
  success: function(html){
    //I wanted to re-use 'projDets' that I'm passing in the 
    //'data' part of my code..                  
  }
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "edited 35 secs ago, Nick Craver" --> May as well not bother answering... nick will post soon :D

Comment: @ILMV - Too busy with work, but he just needs to reference `projDetailsArray` :)

Comment: "edited 2 mins ago, Nick Craver" --> dum de dum!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the `$.ajax` parameter in a closure, set up the "data" value as a local variable, and then reference it both for the "data" value and inside the "success" function:

```
$.ajax(function() {
  var data = {
    projDets: projDetailArray
    // ...
  };
  return {
    url: // your URL here..
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    datatype:'html',
    error: function(){
      alert('Error loading Project Information');     
    },
    success: function(html){
      // just reference "data" here!          
    }
  };
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Pritish - a quick and dirty way would be to store the json array in a jquery .data() object and then retrieve it as required.

1st, set the data: element to a named array:

```
// set 'outside' of the $ajax call
var projDetailsData = {projDets : projDetailsArray};
// now store it in a div data object
$("#targetDiv").data("myparams", projDetailsData);

// the data part of the $ajax call
data: projDetailsData,
```

to retrieve it again:

```
// get the value stored and call the $ajax method again with it
var projDetailsDataCopy = $("#targetDiv").data("myparams");
```

worth a try maybe!!

jim

**[edit]** - also, you could of course store the array in a module level vaiable  -yuk!! :)

Comment: When I try that in the success() function and try to print it out using alert(projDetailsArrayCopy), I get 'undefined'..

Comment: oh, sorry, i thought you wanted to save and restore the array for use as the parameter in the $ajax method. i think because of closure, you won't be able to access the array from within the success function. sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: maybe, you could add an additonal parameter onto the success function i.e success: function(html, projDetailsData){ and then use it that way - no??

Comment: I tried the other solution, and it worked just the way I wanted!

Comment: yes, now that i fully understand the question, i can see that :)